# Is it possible to have an 'or' or 'and' operator inside an 'eq' or 'ne' comparison in perl?

Tags: perl, compare, operators

Is it possible to shorten this scenario:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $tests = [-1,0,1,2,];

foreach my $test (@$tests){
    if ($test ne 0 and $test ne -1){ # THIS LINE
       print "$test - Success\n";
    }else{
       print "$test - Error\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
-1 - Error
0 - Error
1 - Success
2 - Success
```

Into something similar to this where you can put a set of conditions inside the comparison statment (I know this code does not work, is an example of a similar syntax I am searching for):

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $tests = [-1,0,1,2,];

foreach my $test (@$tests){
    if ($test ne (-1 or 0) ){ # THIS LINE
       print "$test - Success\n";
    }else{
       print "$test - Error\n";
    }
}
```

The use case would be something like this

```perl
foreach my $i (0..$variable){
    test 1
    if ($test->{a}->{$variable}->{b} ne 1 and $test->{a}->{$variable}->{b} ne 0){
        ...
    }
    # test 2
    if ($test->{a}->{$variable}->{c} ne 3 and $test->{a}->{$variable}->{c} ne 4){
        ...
    }
}
```

Some syntax like that would simplify a lot writing that type of tests without having to create new variables to make the code easy to read.

Comment: Technically, `$test ne 0` is incorrect, because it is doing stringwise comparison with a number. What you are doing will work as intended if you want to exclude the exact *string* `"0"` from matching. It will return true for other false values, like the empty string, undefined, `0 ` (zero with space), etc. If you do want to do numerical matching, you should use the operator `!=`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use [`List::Util::any`](https://perldoc.perl.org/List::Util#any) or [`List::Util::all`](https://perldoc.perl.org/List::Util#all):

```
if (any { $test != $_ } 0, 1) { ... }
if (all { $test != $_ } 0, 1) { ... }
```

is similar to

```
if ($test != 0 || $test != 1) { ... }
if ($test != 0 && $test != 1) { ... }
```

Note that `List::Util` is a core module, which means that you don't have to install anything for this to work. Just add `use List::Util qw(any all)` to your script.